# UserExtensions static class works in Development configuration but not Release/Production

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I configured a static class to extend the `ClaimsPrincipal` static class and a `SystemRoles` static class to declare group/role values to be used throughout the app. Below are simplified versions of the roles/methods to remove any client specific values, but still demonstrate a real use case.

```
namespace App.Authentication
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper extension methods for checking role membership.  
    /// </summary>
    public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if user has the System Administrator role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="principal"></param>
        /// <returns>bool</returns>
        public static bool IsSysAdmin(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal != null && 
                   (
                       principal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, SystemGroups.SysAdmin) 
                    || principal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, SystemRoles.SysAdmin)
                   );
        }
        public static bool IsManager(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal != null && 
                   (
                       principal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, SystemGroups.Manager) 
                    || principal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, SystemRoles.Manager)
                   );
        }

        public static bool CanManageWorkersAcrossBranches(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            return principal != null && principal.IsSysAdmin() || principal.IsManager();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace App.Authentication
{
    public class SystemGroups
    {
        public const string Manager = "Manager";
        public const string SysAdmin = "SysAdmin";

        // SysAdmin is tacked on to all role combinations as that role is granted access to all parts of the application

        public const string CanManageWorkersAcrossBranches = "Manager, SysAdmin";

    }

    public class SystemRoles
    {
        public const string Manager = @"DOMAIN\Manager";
        public const string SysAdmin = @"DOMAIN\SysAdmin";

        // SysAdmin is tacked on to all role combinations as that role is granted access to all parts of the application

        public const string CanManageWorkersAcrossBranches = @"DOMAIN\Manager, DOMAIN\SysAdmin";

    }
}
```

When using either of the methods in a Controller or view when running in development mode, they work as expected. However when using them in production mode, they always return false.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkerProfileListViewModel>> GetWorkerProfile()
    {
        var profiles = this._profileService.AllWorkerProfiles(activeOnly: false);

        // If a user cannot view workers across branches, then filter the data down to their branch only.
        // This returns `false` when it should return `true`
        if (!User.CanManageWorkersAcrossBranches())
        {
            var currentWorker = await this._workerService.GetCurrentWorkerAsync(User);
            profiles = profiles.Where(p => p.BranchCode == currentWorker.BranchCode);
        }

        return profiles.Select(wp => new WorkerProfileListViewModel(wp));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Using `principal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, SystemRoles.SysAdmin)` was failing because the claims have the SID as the value, rather than the human readable name used to configure the AD user group, which is the same value(s) used in the `SystemRoles` static class.

Replacing `principal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, SystemRoles.SysAdmin)` with `principal.IsInRole(SystemRoles.SysAdmin)` works for both the dev env where a `ClaimsTransformer` is used as well as in the deployed env where there is no transformer and actual user accounts are configured with various user groups / roles.